# How to insert joint account data for single bank account using oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I managed to add one customer on a multiple accounts (current,saving). But I am struggling to add more customers for a single account to make it Joint account. (One account can have more customers).

**This is my account table**

```
create type account_type as object(
accNum number,
accType varchar2(15),
balance number, 
bID ref branch_type,
inRate number,
limitOfFreeOD number,
custID ref customer_type,
openDate DATE)
/
create table account_table of account_type(
primary key (accNum))
/
```

**This is customer table**

```
create type customerName as object(
title varchar2(10),
firstName varchar2(20),
surName varchar2(20))
not final
/

create type customerAddress as object(
street varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
postCode varchar2(20))
not final
/

create type custhomeContact as object(
custHomephone varchar2(15))
not final
/

create type customer_type as object(
custID number,
cName customerName,
cAddress customerAddress,
cHomeContact custhomeContact,
/
create table customer of customer_type(
primary key (custID))
/
```

**Here I am inserting values for a customer who have multiple accounts.**

```
insert into account_table
select account_type('1001','current','820.50',ref(b),'0.030','800',ref(c),'01-May-11')
from branch b, customer c
where b.bID = '901'
and c.custID = '1500';
/

insert into account_table 
select account_type('1010','saving','2155',ref(b),'0.010','0',ref(c),'08-Mar-10')
from branch b, customer c
where b.BID = '906'
and c.custID = '1500';
/
```

**Here is the wrong attempt for joint account entry**

```
insert into account_table 
select account_type('1002','current','2600',ref(b),'0.030','1000',ref(c),'10-Apr-13')
from branch b, customer c
where b.BID = '912'
and c.custID = '1502'
and c.custID = '1500';
/
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: If an account can have multiple customers, can you consider a separate table for that?

Comment: Of course this is the exact point but I’m struggling how to do that. Any help?